# I'm looking to find a power series for a solution f where $zf''(z)+f(z)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, power-series

I'm looking to find a power series for a solution f where $zf''(z)+f(z)=0$

and $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$
and with the assumption $\sum_{k=1}^∞{a_k z^k}=0$

So far I have done this:

$\sum_{k=1}^∞{k^2 a_k z^{k+1}}$+$\sum_{k=1}^∞{a_k z^k}=0$

and $\sum_{k=1}^∞{k^2 a_k z^{k+1}}$=$\sum_{k=1}^∞{k^2 a_{k-1} z^{k}}$, where $a_{k-1}=0$

Thus we can then assume that

$k^2a_{k-1}+a_{k}$=0

$a_{k}=-k^2 a_{k-1}$

But this is where I get stuck because from the original assumption $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$ , one would assume $a_0=0$, $a_1$ but this doesn't make sense with $a_{k}=-k^2 a_{k-1}$

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should first multiply both sides by $z$ then make an exponential substitution to get an equation with constant coefficients. The equation as it is given is not analytic at 0.

Comment: The closed-form solution is going to be $y=c_1\ln|z|+c_0$ which is going to present a problem with your initial conditions. You might want to center your Taylor Series about $z_0=1$ rather than about $z_0=0$.

Comment: I am assuming that you are required to find a series solution. $z=0$ is what is called a regular singular point. You should look in your textbook for the method of finding the indicial equation and its solution then getting a solution in the form $y=z^r\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k$.